# Burninate the [rendering-plain-text] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [rendering-plain-text](/questions/tagged/rendering-plain-text) tag seems fairly useless and only had two questions before I re-tagged, and edited, them.  Hopefully this picture will convince you to do so.

[image: Burninate!]

Comment: Just removing it from all posts effectively burninates the tag.  It should be automatically removed from the tag cache within 24 hours.

Comment: Really? That's nice.

Comment: Unless it gets used again...

Comment: It should be okay since those questions were asked a number of years ago.